keratin vs acetone
If I soak some fingernail clippings and hairs (both are mainly keratin) in a sealed bottle of 100% pure acetone for one week, what will happen?
The only thing I expect is that the acetone will remove almost all water content from the samples, perhaps deforming them.  My main concern is not about deformation, but instead about whether the samples will break apart and dissolve into the acetone.
So, will the samples break apart?  What is the rough time constant for this (instead of just answering for one week)?

Definitely not.

Remember that acetone is sold as a nail varnish remover. If it dissolved fingernails then this would not be possible

@Waylander Yes, it's this common usage that leads me to ask this question.  It's surprising that acetone can dissolve and break glue bonds and dissolve some plastics, but it supposedly does absolutely nothing to skin/nails/hair...so I am curious if there is some small effect that can be seen after one week.
